Compare each 'element in a list' with another 'Set'
I've

A - Type<List>, complete list of products,
B - Type<Set> -  products in the cart, and is always a subset of 'A'

From the list of products 'A', I want to check if each of them is already in the Cart (Set B), and treat them differently.
I'm using forEach() method on list.
Attaching the code, and output
class Product {
  final String id;
  final String title;
  final int price;

  Product({required this.id, required this.title, required this.price});
}

List<Product> allProducts = [
  Product(id: '1', title: 'Groovy Shorts', price: 12),
  Product(id: '2', title: 'Karati Kit', price: 34),
  Product(id: '3', title: 'Denim Jeans', price: 54),
  Product(id: '4', title: 'Red Backpack', price: 14)
];

Set<Product> subProducts = {
  Product(id: '1', title: 'Groovy Shorts', price: 12),
  Product(id: '2', title: 'Karati Kit', price: 34),
};

void main() {
  print(subProducts
      .contains(Product(id: '1', title: 'Groovy Shorts', price: 12)));

  print('----');

  allProducts.forEach((product) {
    print(product.id);
    print(subProducts.contains(product));
  });

  
}


Output

Restarted application in 136ms.
flutter: false
flutter: ----
flutter: 1
flutter: false
flutter: 2
flutter: false
flutter: 3
flutter: false
flutter: 4
flutter: false

For 1 & 2 above, I expected 'true'
For the products already in Set 'B' ( Product 1, Product 2 in this case), I was expecting the output to be 'true', but the output is false for Products 1, 2
It seems my logic is falling short..need help fixing it.

Your Product class does not override the == and .hashCode, so you are not comparing objects based on the properties but only based on if they are the exact same object in memory (which are the default == behavior).

If the ordering of the items in the List do not matter, I'd make that a set too.  Then you can do set arithmetic on them.

Welcome to Stack Overflow! Please do not add answers to the question body itself. Instead, you should add it as an answer. Answering your own question is allowed and even encouraged.

Before you can meaningfully compare instances of Product you have to override the equality operator == and the functionhashCode (see also comment of julemand101).
To see what I mean consider:
class Product {
  final String id;
  final String title;
  final int price;

  Product({
    required this.id,
    required this.title,
    required this.price,
  });
}

void main() {
  final product1 = Product(id: '1', title: 'Groovy Shorts', price: 12);
  final product2 = Product(id: '1', title: 'Groovy Shorts', price: 12);

  print(product1 == product2); // Prints false
}

The program above prints false, since product1 and product2 are distinct objects which happen to have the same instance fields.
Instead of manually overriding the equality operator and function hashCode, you could use this mixin from the package equatable:
import 'package:equatable/equatable.dart';

class Product with EquatableMixin {
  final String id;
  final String title;
  final int price;

  Product({
    required this.id,
    required this.title,
    required this.price,
  });

  @override
  List<Object?> get props => [id, title, price];
}

void main() {
  final product1 = Product(id: '1', title: 'Groovy Shorts', price: 12);
  final product2 = Product(id: '1', title: 'Groovy Shorts', price: 12);

  print(product1 == product2); // Prints true
}


As @julemand101 suggested, you have to override == and hashCode to make it work as expected. equatable package does it automatically for you. You just need to override the props with the list of your object properties, as their example provided
import 'package:equatable/equatable.dart';

class Person extends Equatable {
  const Person(this.name);

  final String name;

  @override
  List<Object> get props => [name]; // add your object properties here...
}

